# Register system with JQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, redirect

I have a register system on a website at *** When someone registers, it shows the error or if it is accepted, it shows "true". The javascript file (http://pastebin.com/mv9CWZcT) is meant to redirect the user if the register is successful but it is not working for me!
I have used this script before and I do know that it works but not here for some reason?

I am at school and cannot view any error dialogs etc.

Thanks, Josh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your AJAX is returning two line breaks and `true`, rather than just true. Use `$.trim(html)` before seeing if the value is `true`.